# Pegar tamanho da tela no xml

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de que Layout ficasse com o tamanho da tela na horizontal. Mas, quando a tela virasse, ele continuasse com o mesmo tamanho.
Fiz um pequeno esboço de como eu pretendo que fique:

[image: Exemplo]

O xml atual é apenas :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"></LinearLayout>
```

**Editado**

Acabei usando mesmo o codigo no create da acivity:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int minimo=Math.min(dm.widthPixels,dm.heightPixels);
View layoutAlto = findViewById(R.id.login_layoutalto);
    layoutAlto.getLayoutParams().width = minimo;
```

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Como assim? A imagem não aparece aqui pra mim.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UPS1Z.png

Comment: Ainda não consigo ver :/ Deixa eu ver se entendi: você quer que o layout fique do mesmo tamanho, independente da orientação da tela(paisagem ou retrato)?

Comment: A largura pelo menos. Em modo retrato ele preenche a largura, em modo paisagem ele não muda a largura.

Comment: Você quer que fique como está no esboço ou quer que em modo paisagem ela ocupe a largura toda da tela? Poste o xml.

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago como está o seu arquivo de layout atualmente?

Comment: Fiquei com a mesma dúvida do @ramaral

Comment: Eu quero que fique como no esboço! Eu não postei o xml pq e so um layout com fill_parent.

Comment: O correto é que a largura do layout se adapte de acordo com orientação do dispositivo. Essa largura pode ser diferente de acordo com os diversos modelos de dispositivos que temos no mercado. Caso vc realmente necessite do layout de acordo com o esboço, vc terá que pegar a dimensão de menor comprimento e configurar no layout_width em tempo de execução. Avisa ai sua necessidade, talvez possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Rodrigo, se conseguiu resolver o problema, poste a solução como uma resposta logo abaixo e marque como "aceita".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não lhe vou dar uma solução pronta porque ela seria um pouco extensa, além que não encontro solução para o caso em que a aplicação seja executada inicialmente em modo paisagem.

Para obter a largura e altura de uma *view* que tenham esse valores declarados no *xml* como `match_parent` ou `wrap_content` use este código:

```
private final int largura;
private final int altura;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    final View aSuaView = findViewById(R.id.aSuaView);
    aSuaView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 

        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
                aSuaView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                //Coloca a largura igual à altura
                largura = aSuaView.getWidth();
                altura = aSuaView.getHeight();
            }
        });
}
```

Para saber se o dispositivo está em modo paisagem use:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

Você deve guardar o valor da largura que a *view* tem no modo retrato e quando passar a modo paisagem atribui-lo a ela.

Para guardar o valor pode usar o `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 1):

O único modo de fazer isso é mudando a largura em tempo de execução. Já que o xml não suporta operações matemáticas. No onCreate :

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int minimo=Math.min(dm.widthPixels,dm.heightPixels);
View layoutView = findViewById(R.id.iddolayout);
layoutView .getLayoutParams().width = minimo;
```

Usando a operação min, porque é menor dimensao que será a largura do layout.

Answer (score -2):

Para o que você quer é só usar o layout_weight. Segue o exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#123">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#678">
    </LinearLayout>       

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, a linha vermelha não está dividindo o layout e sim mostrando a largura.